# Determining next correct move for an image carousel in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I am working on a circular image carousel in Javascript.

It needs to be circular in the sense that, if the 0 position slide is currently selected and "Previous" is pressed, it will jump to the last position slide. If the last position slide is currently selected and "Next" is pressed, it will jump to the 0 position slide.

Another program handles the overall slide, but I can:

- Detect current position *after* shift with `slide.current` - the first position is 0
- Detect the total number of slides (does not change until page reload) with `slide.items.length`
- Fire my own `nextSlide` and `previousSlide` functions after the slide program completes its own complementary functions
- Manually change the currently selected slide and pointer position using `slideTo()` in the slide API
- Know automatically that the first visible slide, after page load, is the total number of items (3 to n) divided by 2, rounded up

Here's what I have:

```
var currentSlide = slide.current;
var lastSlide = 'undefined';

function nextSlide(){
    currentSlide = slide.current;

    if(lastSlide == 'undefined'){
        lastSlide = currentSlide - 1;
    } else if (lastSlide == 0) {
        lastSlide = currentSlide;
    } else{
        lastSlide = lastSlide + 1;
    }

    if (lastSlide == currentSlide) {
        slide.activate(0);
    }
}

function previousSlide(){
    currentSlide = slide.current;

    if(lastSlide == 'undefined'){
        lastSlide = currentSlide + 1;
    } else if (lastSlide == slide.items.length - 1) {
        lastSlide = currentSlide;
    } else{
        lastSlide = lastSlide - 1;
    }

    if (lastSlide == currentSlide) {
        slide.activate(sly.items.length - 1);
    }
}
```

This fails when you mix `previousSlide` calls and `nextSlide` calls. The `lastSlide` variable becomes incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

- There's no need to declare lastSlide's value to be "undefined". If you declare a variable without assigning any value, it becomes undefined by default.
- Given that slide acts as an object, it would make more sense for nextSlide and previousSlide acting as methods instead of stand alone functions.
- lastSlide value should depend on the value of currentSlide.
- Strict comparison operators should be used to avoid type jumbling in the future. (=== instead of ==)

Comment: Thank you for that, I will address some of that in my final version.

Do you have any input on the logic problem I'm having? Everything else in my code is functional, I just need the logic to be figured out.